# flutter app on restart not showing home page after hot reload it works

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm beginner at flutter app development.i'm trying to fetch more then ten pages from api with for loop and addall results in list.for that i created future function and statefulwidget
here my code is

```
    import 'dart:convert';

    import 'package:MovieAPi/infopage.dart';
    import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    List data = [];
    Future<void> _getMovies() async {
      for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        var url =
            "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=1dce78a9836cf6fbc01190431d9443fe&page=$i";
        http.Response response = await http.get(url);
        var JsonBody = json.decode(response.body);
        data.addAll(JsonBody['results']);
      }
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            textTheme: TextTheme(
              title: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
              subtitle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
            ),
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: MovieTile(),
        );
      }
    }

    class MovieTile extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MovieTileState createState() => _MovieTileState();
    }

    class _MovieTileState extends State<MovieTile> {
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        setState(() {
          _getMovies();
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Movies", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              bottomOpacity: 0.0,
              shadowColor: Colors.white,
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            ),
            body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                String image = data[index]['poster_path'];
                String title = data[index]['title'];
                String release_date = data[index]['overview'];
                String id = data[index]['id'].toString();
                String vote = data[index]['vote_average'].toString();
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    return Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => InfoMovie(id)));
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 10),
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: 500.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                            "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original$image",
                          ),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            offset: Offset(1, 9),
                            blurRadius: 10,
                            color: Colors.black26,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.black26,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: 0,
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                                ),
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    title,
                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .title
                                        .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                                  Text(
                                    release_date,
                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .subtitle
                                        .copyWith(
                                            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9)),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                    maxLines: 3,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    softWrap: true,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            top: 20,
                            left: 10,
                            child: Container(
                              height: 50,
                              width: 50,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6),
                                      width: 1)),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 40,
                                  width: 40,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      vote,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontSize: 18,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ));
      }
    }
```

frist when i open app showing nothing
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVfYD.png)
only blank screen
and when i hot reload then showing results
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29nsi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `setState` is not necessary in `initState`. Secondly, since `ListView.builder` is the root element of your page body, you cannot directly see the `data` content because it's empty `data = []` at app startup.
To solve this, better you try something like this

```
return Scaffold(
  body: data.length > 0 ? ListView.builder(
    // ...
  ) : Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  ),
)
```

Also, it's better you put your `List data` variable and `_getMovies` function in `_MovieTileState` like this

```
class _MovieTileState extends State<MovieTile> {
  List data;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    data = [];
    _getMovies();
  }

  Future<void> _getMovies() async {
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      var url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=1dce78a9836cf6fbc01190431d9443fe&page=$i";
      http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      var JsonBody = json.decode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        data.addAll(JsonBody['results']);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          // ...
        ),
        body: data.length > 0 ? ListView.builder(
          // ...
        ) : Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried this and now this show only circularProgressIndicator not showing any list of movie when i make hot reload then that showing me list not on restart